# Checking Linux Disk space

Tags: linux, centos

I want to check the disk free space in mu RHEL/Centos box. If I use `df`, sometimes, the command just hangs. (because of NFS issue or something)

I want to create a monitoring script and want to monitor disk free space usage. I do not want to use `df`, as it *could* hang.

I thought about "`tune2fs -l`" but the values does not match the output from "`df`"

How do i get the free disk space *without* using `df`?

Thanks in Advance
Vijay

Comment: how about "stat -f /" or whatever mount point.  stat -f /
  File: "/"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Blocks: Total: 5201804    Free: 3507293    Available: 3245133    Size: 4096
Inodes: Total: 1313760    Free: 994569    The output is in bytes, if you want to parse it the better way see man page for stat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have issues with remote FS you can try **-l** from df to show only local FS (without smb, nfs,...) ex.

```
df -hl
```

Answer (score 2):

For monitoring, your answer is Nagios. You might need to solve the NFS issue to get ahead.

Comment: Agree with Nagios, but he may monitor only local filesystems through snmp or even scripts.  And the NFS isn't an "issue", it's just df trying to get the information over the network and, depending on the size of the disks, hanging on while it counts up the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one particular filesystem type, you can also use -t:

```
$ df -P -t ext3
Filesystem              1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-root     2064208    383928   1575436      20% /
/dev/mapper/system-var      4128448   1601360   2317400      41% /var
/dev/mapper/system-usr     10321208   9241500    555500      95% /usr
/dev/mapper/system-srv      4128448   2957240    961496      76% /srv
/dev/mapper/system-opt      2567984   1926352    615556      76% /opt
/dev/sda2                    253871     54964    185800      23% /boot
/dev/mapper/system-home   190942900 168859288  20145164      90% /home
/dev/mapper/system-fast    82569904  66171404  12204452      85% /home/fast
```